# ARM Template listkeys() fails to find Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-rm-template

I'm creating an ARM Template to deploy both an Azure Search instance and a Function App that depends on the Azure Search instance. As part of that I'm trying to pre-populate the Function Apps app settings with the Search Service's API Key.

I'm doing this by adding the following into the value of one of the app settings of the `FunctionAppSite`:

```
[listKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2015-08-19').key1]
```

I get the searchServiceId in the variables sections

```
[resourceId('Microsoft.Search/searchServices', parameters('SearchServiceName'))]
```

The `FunctionAppSite` component lists dependencies on the `AppServicePlan`, `StorageAccount` and `SearchService`.

When I deploy the template the Search Service gets created then an error occurs because `listkeys` couldn't find the Search Service. This happens about .25s after the service is created.

I'm pretty sure I have the syntax around the listkeys correct and the problem is just the timing, no sure how I can slow it down though. I tried forcing the `StorageAccount` to depend on the `SearchService` in my template, hoping the dependency chain would slow things down enough, but the `listkeys` error happens after the Search Service is created, but before the `StorageAccount` is created.

The full template can be found [here](https://github.com/hutchcodes/Jekyll-Search-With-Azure-Functions/blob/master/JekyllSearch.json) and there is a 'Deploy to Azure' button on the readme.md of that repo if you want to see it in action.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, looking at provider operations for `Microsoft.Search`:

```
Microsoft.Search/register/action
Microsoft.Search/checkNameAvailability/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/write
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/read
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/delete
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/start/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/stop/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/listAdminKeys/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/regenerateAdminKey/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/createQueryKey/action
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/queryKey/read
Microsoft.Search/searchServices/queryKey/delete
```

this is how you do it:

```
 "[listAdminKeys(variables('searchServiceId'), '2015-08-19').PrimaryKey]"
```

To list provider operations:

```
$ops = (Get-AzureRmProviderOperation -OperationSearchString */*).Operation
```

Comment: Can you comment on how you looked at the provider operations?